# How to suppress font information from pdftex terminal output?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, logging

I would like that pdfTeX printed terminal logs in the same format as *TeX*. Font information (especially when a lot of fonts are used) makes the log output hard to read.

In the following example how to suppress `{/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}` and `</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>` from terminal output?

```
$ pdftex '\relax A\bye'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
[1{/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]</usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on texput.pdf (1 page, 8454 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Compare above example with this:

```
$ tex '\relax A\bye'
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
[1]
Output written on texput.dvi (1 page, 208 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Comment: This is one reason I especially like pdfTeX in comparison to other engines!

Comment: The thing is that the font information is *relevant* in the first case and not the second because a DVI is just a bunch of boxes, whereas a PDF uses fonts, whether embedded or not. You can produce a DVI file without the fonts. You can't produce a PDF without them. So you are comparing apples and oranges. The best way to handle log messages you don't care about is to use a tool to parse the log file which you can customise to your liking. Many editors do this, though sadly minus the customisation in many cases.

Comment: If you want to suppress that information, you need to modify the sources of `pdftex` and recompile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate the listing of fonts loaded because this is not important information when things are OK. Of course, if there is an problem with fonts then this listing may be useful. I have the terminal with limited height and important information (about overfull boxes, about OPmac warning, about undeclared references etc.) are scrolled due to this non-useful listing about plenty of fonts.

I understand that LaTeX users don't read the terminal output because they have tons of non-useful lines here. But this is not the case of plain TeX users. So, I disagree that the fonts information is *very* relevant. They may be relevant only when we need them.

My personal solution is very far from optimum. I am using the `grep` at the pipe of standard output (in Unix) in order to suppress the font information printed by pdftex on the terminal. So, the very usable information aren't scrolled. The `pdfcsplain` command is implemented in my computer as:

```
#!/bin/bash
pdftex -fmt pdfcsplain $@ | grep -Pv '[^\s]{79,79}|pdfTeX warning|fixed one|^$'
```

Comment: I have installed grep (GNU grep) 2.25 (for the `-P` option), but the script suppresses nothing with a simple test file containing just `abc\bye`

Comment: If there is a font listing with more than one line then these lines are suppressed. Try the file `\input opmac \fontfam[catalog]\end` for example.

Comment: Your workaround is not always good, because sometimes we need to use interactive mode. More clean solution would be to recompile pdftex. To make the job easier for me, can you please give any example how to make modifications to pdftex?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I know this problem, I have said that it is far from optimum. I am using another command when I need the interactive processing. IMHO this problem is matured to "feature request" to pdftex developers.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the wrong things: the right comparison is with

```
> tex '\relax A\bye' && dvips texput
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
[1]
Output written on texput.dvi (1 page, 208 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
This is dvips(k) 5.996 Copyright 2016 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2016.06.12:1635' -> texput.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
[1]
```

The information about the font files included in the PDF is *very* relevant. Actually, I wish there was at least an option for showing which `.vf` and `.tfm` files are loaded (though this is possible with `-recorder`).

If you really want to suppress the font information from `pdftex`, you have to modify its sources and recompile it.